# Evaluation of a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

As an intermediate step to a problem, I would like to know whether or not the following is true:

> Let $0<r<1$, and let $\zeta_j$ denote the $n$th root of unity. Then define polynomial index by $j$ as
>   $$ f_j(z) = \frac{z\prod_{i} (z-r^{1/n}\zeta_i)}{z-r^{1/n}\zeta_j}.$$
>   Then $f_j(r^{1/n}\zeta_j) = f_k(r^{1/n}\zeta_k)$ for any $j$ and $k$.

The trouble I have proving or disproving this guess is that I couldn't directly plug in the value, as the denominator would then become zero. On the other hand, if I try to cancel out one linear factor from both the numerator and the denominator and try it evaluate from there, the expansion would be very messy and I don't seem to be able to figure out what it would evaluate to. I would appreciate any suggestions or hints.

Comment: write $f_j(z)=g(z)+(r^{1/n}\zeta_j)(g(z)/(z-z_j)), g(z_j)=0$ so the ratio evaluates to $g'(z_j)$ so now one can substitute as we know $g$ and we get $f_j(z_j)=(r^{1/n}\zeta_j)(n(r^{1/n}\zeta_j)^{n-1})$ etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $\prod_{i} (z-r^{1/n}\zeta_i) = z^n -r$ and use L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: If I write it in this form, I would still not be able to evaluate it because the denominator is zero?

Comment: @BihuDuo calculate $\lim_{z\to r^{1/n}\zeta_j}f(z)$,  L'Hospital's Rule helps you when the denominator will become 0.